# How to use system\environment variables in .NET string?

Tags: c#, windows, environment-variables, system-variable

I have path variable which I got from my appsettings:

```
var path="%TEMP%\myapplication\data";
```

I am trying to use it in `Directory.CreateDirectory(path)` method. But I got new folder in my application *bin* folder instead of *C:\Users\Evgeny\AppData\Local\Temp\myapplication\data*.

Should I replace `%TEMP%` manually?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use [`System.Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.expandenvironmentvariables.aspx) like so:

```
String concretePath = Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables(@"%TEMP%\myapplication\data");
```